# Modal CDialog doesn't find resources (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm having some trouble to create a very simple CDialog application. My goal is to start a CDialog instance in the main function of my code, wait for it to get closed and continue. The problem here comes when I add a picture to the Dialog, it just **does not appear**. I even tried programatically to load it to a CStatic where I found a workaround. If I use `CBitmap::LoadBitmap(...)` it returns the error ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND, but if I use `::LoadImage(GetModulehandle(0), ...)` it does work. So it seems the problem is the module handle. An important note is that if I try to do my app as modeless (Using a CWinApp) everything works flawlessly, but I need a Modal CDialog! I'm not giving up my main function. Thank you in advance.

Just in case it might be of use, here is the code (almost all):

MyDialog.h

```
#include<afxwin.h>
#include"resource.h"

class CMyDialog: public CDialog{
public:
    enum{ IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };
    CMyDialog();
    ~CMyDialog();
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

MyDialog.cpp

```
#include"MyDialog.h"

CMyDialog::CMyDialog(): CDialog(CMyDialog::IDD){
}

CMyDialog::~CMyDialog(){
}

void CMyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX){
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

main.cpp

```
#include"MyDialog.h"

int main(){
    CMyDialog mDialog;
    mDialog.DoModal();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no "modal" or "modeless" application. Modal or modeless refers to a dialog's behaviour relative to the rest application, ie whether it allows user interaction with the other windows in the application.
But in your case the dialog is the only window...

As for your question, I think the problem is due to not having created the application as required. Try creating a new "Dialog-Based" MFC Application, not just using main() yourself.

Comment: This window is going to be part of a larger project and it needs to halt interaction with other windows when it appears, that's what I meant by modal but I used it wrong, I'm new with MFC and VC++ in general. I didn't want to use the wizard because it creates a project that basically IS visual studio's UI, which does not allow me to understand how small components of it work. And yes, the main function lacked some instructions but now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, not sure whether this way you can block the calling application. The call will likely return as soon as your application is loaded. Maybe consider making it a dll instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an MFC code can't run without beeing initialized .

If you want to have a command line application using the MFC you need to call AfxWinInit.

The wizard will create code like this:

```
int main()
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

    if (hModule != nullptr)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, nullptr, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            wprintf(L"Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n");
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
```

Using a dialog based application or any other non-command line application, will create a CWinApp singleton. Upon creation of the CWinApp object inside your process the AfxWinInit function will be called.

Mainly your code fails because the resource handle isn't set. So your resource can't be found by the MFC.

Comment: You have no idea how thankful I am. The problem is that I couldn't use the wizard because I'm constrained to use VS 2010 (for some odd reason) and the wizard generates a very complex window system as a singleton. If it wouldn't be asking to much of my part, why is it that I was able to load the Bitmap using LoadImage? Does this function call AfxWinInit()? Thank you a lot!

Comment: A windows system as a singleton? No, There is usually only a CWinApp singleton. This singleton may host hundreds of windows.If you have an Windows application and you use the MFC, there must be a CWinApp derived class and this calls AfxWinInit... so your code might work. Same for Extension DLLs that live inside an MFC application and for standard DLLs...